# Count words from a text file of unknown but massive size in C using linked list

Tags: c, memory, text, count, linked-list

I know how to count the words.  I'm using a linked list of `struct`s containing the word and the count.  It works on small files, but requires me to define a maximum text length.  For all I know, the text files may be in excess of multiple gigabytes.  How can I change this to not require the `#define MAX_TEXT_LENGTH`?  Should I use `malloc()` and if so, what exactly should I apply `malloc()` to?  The final goal is to then sort everything in alphabetical order and print the words with frequencies, but that should be easy after I read the words and have my counts.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_WORD 512
#define MAX_TEXT_LENGTH 10000

typedef struct word
{
char *str;              /* Stores the word */
int freq;               /* Stores the frequency */
struct word *pNext;     /* Pointer to the next word counter in the list */
} Word;

// ===========================================
//             FUNCTION PROTOTYPES
//============================================

int getNextWord(FILE *fp, char *buf, int bufsize);   /* Given function to get words */
void addWord(char *pWord);                          /* Adds a word to the list or updates exisiting word */
void show(Word *pWordcounter);        /* Outputs a word and its count of occurrences */
Word* createWordCounter(char *word);  /* Creates a new WordCounter structure */

// ===========================================
//             GLOBAL VARIABLES
//============================================

Word *pStart = NULL;                  /* Pointer to first word counter in the list */
int totalcount = 0;                  /* Total amount of words */
int uniquecount = 0;                /* Amount of unique words */


// ===========================================
//                 MAIN
//============================================      

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE * fp;          /* File pointer */
    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");    /* Read text from here */
    char buf[MAX_WORD];     /* buf to hold the words */
    int size = MAX_TEXT_LENGTH; /* Size */

    Word *pCounter = NULL;  /* Pointer to Word counter */

    /* Read all words from text file */
    while (getNextWord(fp, buf, size))
    {
        /* Add the word to the list */
        addWord(buf); 
        /* Increment the total words counter */
        totalcount++;
    }

    /* Loop through list and figure out the number of unique words */
    pCounter = pStart;
    while(pCounter != NULL)
    {
        uniquecount++;
        pCounter = pCounter->pNext;
    }

    /* Print Summary */
    printf("\nSUMMARY:\n\n");
    printf("   %d words\n", totalcount);    /* Print total words */
    printf("   %d unique words\n", uniquecount); /* Print unique words */

    /* List the words and their counts */
    pCounter = pStart;
    while(pCounter != NULL)
    {
        show(pCounter);
        pCounter = pCounter->pNext;
    }
    printf("\n");

    /* Free the allocated  memory*/
    pCounter = pStart;
    while(pCounter != NULL)
    {
        free(pCounter->str);        
        pStart = pCounter;           
        pCounter = pCounter->pNext;  
        free(pStart);                  
    }
    /* Close file */
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

// ===========================================
//                 FUNCTIONS
//============================================

void show(Word *pWordcounter)
{
    printf("\n%-30s   %5d", pWordcounter->str,pWordcounter->freq);
}

void addWord(char *word)
{
    Word *pCounter = NULL;
    Word *pLast = NULL;

    if(pStart == NULL)
    {
        pStart = createWordCounter(word);
        return;
    }

    /* If the word is in the list, increment its count */
    pCounter = pStart;
    while(pCounter != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(word, pCounter->str) == 0)
        {
            ++pCounter->freq;
            return;
    }
    pLast = pCounter;            
    pCounter = pCounter->pNext;  
}

    /* Word is not in the list, add it */
    pLast->pNext = createWordCounter(word);
}

Word* createWordCounter(char *word)
{
    Word *pCounter = NULL;
    pCounter = (Word*)malloc(sizeof(Word));
    pCounter->str = (char*)malloc(strlen(word)+1);
    strcpy(pCounter->str, word);
    pCounter->freq = 1;
    pCounter->pNext = NULL;
    return pCounter;
}

int getNextWord(FILE *fp, char *buf, int bufsize) {
    char *p = buf;
    char c;

    //skip all non-word characters
    do
    {
        c = fgetc(fp);
        if (c == EOF) 
            return 0;
    } while (!isalpha(c));

    //read word chars
    do
    {
        if (p - buf < bufsize - 1)
        *p++ = tolower(c);
        c = fgetc(fp);
    } while (isalpha(c));

    //finalize word
    *p = '\0';
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What does the downvote mean...did I ask a duplicate question or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on the error John pointed out in his answer... and to add some comments to your overall questions...

> I know how to count the words. I'm using a linked list

> of structs containing the word and the count. It works

> on small files, but requires me to define a maximum text

> length.

> For all I know, the text files may be in excess of

> multiple gigabytes.

Your code looks pretty solid, except for the point below I wouldn't change much.
I believe you MUST put an upper limit on how big any particular "word" can be.
But the overall size of the file? No problem with what you wrote; it is only memory-limitted.

True, a text file can be multiple gigabytes (or even longer).
But it seems like your code will already will handle an effectively UNLIMITED number of UNIQUE words.

btw: I like that you're lower-casing your words; minimizes the list size, finds more "common" words.

Your MAX_WORD size is already 512 characters.
Suggestion 1: consider counting the number of times (if any) you Exceed MAX_WORD size, and print out that status at the end of your run.

> How can I change this to not require the #define MAX_TEXT_LENGTH?

About MAX_TEXT_LENGTH, I think that is an error.  John called that out as well in his answer.  Read on... :-)

> Should I use malloc() and if so, what exactly should I apply malloc() to?

I see no need for more malloc(), you already have a nicely self-growing linked list.

Suggestion 2: just delete MAX_TEXT_LENGTH, I don't see where you need it at all.
In fact, the original code looks like it allows buffer overruns on your "buf" variable (this would be the "error" part).

More specifically, "buf" is only MAX_WORD in capacity, but your original code is telling getNextWord() to use MAX_TEXT_LENGTH, which is a lot (very much) greater than MAX_WORD.

Consider modifying your code to look like the folowing:

```
/* Read all words from text file */

/* original: */
/* while (getNextWord(fp, buf, size)) */
/* NOTE: remeber size was originally MAX_TEXT_LENGTH (error?). */

/* You could just use MAX_WORD here and delete "size" while you're at it. */
while (getNextWord(fp, buf, MAX_WORD))
{
    /* Add the word to the list */
    addWord(buf); 
    /* Increment the total words counter */
    totalcount++;
}
```

> The final goal is to then sort everything in alphabetical order and print

> the words with frequencies, but that should be easy after I read the

> words and have my counts.

r.e. sorting, for a "stretch goal", see suggestion #4, below.

Suggestion 3: Just for fun, you also might want to print a frequency chart of your word lengths at the end.
For example:

```
Freq  : Word Length
 4851 :       1
  205 :       2
  104 :       3
...etc...  
    1 :     406
```

Suggestion 4: instead of growing your list by adding each new word at the end you may get a performance boost if you grow your linked list *in sorted order*, using strcmp() to tell if you went beyond the possible add-point for a new word.  The idea is you would avoid having to walk the entire list each time you add a word that may go in the middle somewhere.  This approach is more complex though, because you'll have to be careful about handle splicing something into mid-list, as well edge cases (like handling new inserts at beginning).

However, it would the list would already be sorted by the time you get to the end of your input file so it may be worth giving this design approach some thought.

Good luck, I think you wrote pretty good code.

Comment: Possibly a 4gig file on a Linux VM

Comment: @ReiHinoX, I was playing with numbers for a worst-case "ugly file".  :-) One could generate a 4gb file w/unique 7-char "words" (a-z only, but 8 chars total since you'll want a space or smth as a separator).  Assuming 1 byte per char, 6-char words only reaches 1.7gb, but 7-char words will generate about 13gb worth of unique "words") so 7 is more than enough for 4gb.  The numbers are ugly for memory consumption and compute operations to generate a linked list for analysis.  A 16gb 64-bit machine could handle that with some ram left over, but seems like it would run for a long time.

Comment: Sounds like fun.  I would encourage you to benchmark various content; a 4gb "random" file, e.g. "aaaaaaa aaaaaab aaaaaac" etc. filled with non-repeating  7-char "words".  You could also look at pulling some text down from Project Gutenberg to benchmark, or maybe offline Wikiepdia (http://bit.ly/1L9SWG6).  Your multi-threading speedups may be limited by the IO capability, especially a on machine with a single spinning hard disk.  Instead of (or in addition to) multi-threading, consider format-aware text stripping that could deal with html, xml, maybe ms-office formats.

Answer (score 1):

The code has an error and MAX_TEXT_LENGTH is not needed as it is. The limit should be to make sure a single word does not exceed the length of the *word* buffer. Change the name of 'buf' to 'nextWordInFileBuffer' in your program to see if it makes more sense.